# How do I scalably sort compressed (gzip) S3 file using AWS-Lambda?

Tags: gzip, aws-lambda

How do I scalably sort compressed (gzip) S3 file using `AWS-Lambda`?
Is there an example of how to do it using `Python` ?
I want to avoid downloading file or renting `EC2` instance.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is unclear. Please Edit the question to add more details. For example, what do you mean by "scalably sort compressed (gzip) S3 file" -- are you sorting a *list* of S3 files, or sorting the *contents* of a file stored in S3, or sorting a list of files within a zip file? Does the zip file contain multiple files? The more you can tell us, the more likely we will be able to provide a good answer.